# HTML5 File Upload Input - onChange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload, onchange

When the user selects files to be uploaded I present one of two buttons to take action on the file(s) based on how many files there are. I get the number of files by including an `onchange=getNumFiles(this)` in the file input tag.

My problem is that I hide the button to take action on the files after the user clicks it, and if the user selects the same file(s) a second time the button is not "re-presented". This is happening because the file upload input never actually *changed* because the input is still holding the original file selection. How can I account for this?

Is there a way to clear the contents of the file upload input? I've tried setting the value to null to no avail. Or is there a different event other than **onchange** that I should be using? hope this makes sense....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I clear an HTML file input with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703228/how-can-i-clear-an-html-file-input-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "*Is there a way to clear the contents of the file upload input*"

Yes, call `.reset()` on the form.

```
$("#myform")[0].reset();
```

Now if the same file is selected again it will correctly trigger a change event since it changed from nothing to something again.

Comment: one question, why exactly do you need the array notation [0] to reference forms?

Comment: Because jQuery doesn't have a .reset() method. .reset is a native method that all forms have, it normally gets called when a `<button type="reset">Reset</button>` is clicked, it resets all inputs back to their default values.

Comment: the only other way to clear a file input is to clone it or remove it and create a new one. you have little to no access to the value of a file input.