# How remove one, two files from input type="file" multiple?

Tags: javascript

```
<input 
    type="file"
    id="fileElem" 
    multiple 
    accept="image/*"
    style="display:none"
    onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">

<a href="#" id="fileSelect">Select some files</a> 

<div id="fileList">
    <p>No files selected!</p>
</div>
```

When I selected 5 files: How to dynamically remove some of them?

I know how clear all files [How can I clear an HTML file input with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703228/how-can-i-clear-an-html-file-input-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#fileElem")[0].files` is a read-only array.

You can get around this by pushing those files into a separate Array though. You can then do whatever you want with that curated list of files. If uploading them to a server is the goal, you can use the `FileReader` API.

Below is a round about way of completely avoiding needing to modify the FileList. Steps:

1. Add normal file input change event listener
2. Loop through each file from change event, filter for desired validation
3. Push valid files into separate array
4. Use `FileReader` API to read files locally
5. Submit valid, processed files to server