# How to reset the file button

Tags: jquery

[image]

I have attached an image. When I try to click "X" icon below the image I am able to remove the file but the file name at right side of "Choose File" is still display. Could anybody tell me how to reset it back.

I am using following code to remove the image.

```
$('div').on('click', '.closeDiv', function(e){
            var closest = $(this).closest('td');
            var id = closest.find('div:first');
            $(this).prev().remove();
            $(this).remove();
            closest.find('span:first').html('');
            $('#'+id).val("");
        })
```

Comment: [Clearing <input type='file' /> using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery)

Comment: [How can I clear an HTML file input with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703228/how-can-i-clear-an-html-file-input-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#file_id').val('');
// It will remove the selected file. Use it inside your function.
```