# Can I reset the seletced file name of an HTML 5 file selector?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html) seems to say that I can’t.

I am using AngularJs, but this is probably not AngularJs specific.

For screen real estate reasons, I display an "Upload file" button.  When clicked, the contents of the screen are replaced by a hidden `<div>` (using `ng-show` and `ng-hide`) which contains a file selector, an “Upload” button and a “Cancel” button.

When the user selects a file, its name is shown by the file selector directive. When the user selects either “Upload” or “Cancel” button, that `<div>` is hidden.

When it reappears, I don’t want it to show the name of the previously selected file.

I realize that I could achieve this by removing the file selector from the DOM and inserting a new one, but was hoping to be able to just set a property.

Again, I only want to clear the selected file name, no set it to another file name.

---

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_fileupload_name.asp says "The name property sets or returns the value of the name attribute of a file upload button". I am at work & will try that when I get home this evening.

Any comments?

Comment: how about clearing the inner html of the `<div>´tag when you hide it so that the next time when you show it, it doesn't have anything ... as designed .-)

Comment: What does "clear" mean? Remvoe from the DOM & reinsert?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I clear an HTML file input with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703228/how-can-i-clear-an-html-file-input-with-javascript)

Comment: Probably this answer would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703228/how-can-i-clear-an-html-file-input-with-javascript

Comment: Where's the relevant code? Some of this issue is clearly angular specific

Comment: @Slava.K Yup, we could close as Dupe, or I can just delete it to save confusion.  Bad research on my part. Sorry.

Comment: @Mawg General recommendation is not to delete duplicate questions because having multiple copies of the same question with different wording is useful as search fodder, because people looking for an answer may use different wording too. Therefore let's close this as Dupe

Comment: First time I ever voted to close my own question :-)

Comment: @Mawg just delete it. It has no long term value