# Can value of input box be set to to empty string on clicking submit button when the input is in a stateless functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to clear the value inside the input  in function Admin after I click the "Add" button? Should i use another class based component instead of a functional component?

I have set the value of one of the input box as : value={props.item} and in the this.setState I update the value of item as item:"".

```
  AddInfo(info){
    let s = this.state.products;
    let obj ={name:""};
    obj.name=info.productName;

    s.push(obj);

    this.setState({
      products:s,
      item:"" //Here i set the value of item equal to an empty string.
    })
    console.log(this.state.products);
  }



function Admin(props){

    let productName="";

    return (
        <div>            
            <input type="text" required placeholder="Product Name" onChange={(e)=>{productName=e.target.value}} value={props.item}></input><br/>

   <button type="Submit" onClick{(e)=>props.AddInfo({productName})}>Add</button>
     </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Hi Hardik, I'd like to answer your question, but please minimize your code snippet. It seems you just copied code to the snippet. Pleas leave only what's relevant to your question, so it is easier to answer. The various routes are irrelevant. AddInfo also seems irrelvant.

Comment: Done. AddInfo isn't irrelevant since I have used this.setState in AddInfo to set this.state.products equal to s and also updated the value of item:"" which i think is something wrong since the value of item never changed in the first place :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to save your input within a local state of the input function:

```
 AddInfo(info){
    let s = this.state.products;
    let obj ={name:""};
    obj.name=info.productName;

    s.push(obj);

    this.setState({
      products:s,
    })
    console.log(this.state.products);
    }



function Admin(props){

    const [productName, setProductName] = useState('');

    return (
        <div>            
            <input type="text" required placeholder="Product Name" onChange={(e)=> setProductName(e.target.value) value={productName}></input><br/>
   <button type="Submit" onClick{(e)=> {props.AddInfo({productName}); setProductName('')}}>Add</button>
 </div>
)
}
```

This will work for you, since you are not mutating the productName variable anymore but now you are saving it in a local state of that input function.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It says 'useState','setproductName' is not defined.

Comment: Did you import useState, and in which lines does it give the error?

Comment: I created a codepen for you: https://codepen.io/Domino987/pen/WVgBOr?editors=1011

Comment: https://codepen.io/hardik150/pen/PMdrKW Used it. Doesn't work for some reason (Sorry I am new to this)

Comment: Sorry I didn't add value={productName}. It worked now.Thank a lot I literally spent the whole day getting this done.

Comment: I used your solution in my code and it works flawlessly, but the same isn't the case with a file input that I have added in my code. Can you please help me out?  https://codepen.io/hardik150/pen/zgmGqz

Comment: You are making the same error again, you have to read some docs to understand what is happening. You cannot create variables in a functional component just like this and expect it to persist (it gets overwritten on every render), you have to use useState for each variable you track: https://codepen.io/Domino987/pen/MNPeRZ?editors=0011

Comment: In this codepen you created, I'll have to give my input some value and in the button write setProductPicture(" ") , right? When I give {productPicture} as a value it shows "This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string."

Comment: The input is a little bit more tricky, the value reset does not work for the file type. Here is another SO answer, which covers it:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42192346/how-to-reset-reactjs-file-input

Comment: I'll try to figure it out :) Would it make more sense to just start from scratch with a class based component instead of a functional component since I want to add features like remove,update etc?

Comment: It depends on the complexity. If you have more than few functions and states, it would be better, since it improves readability and makes it easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

- Admin is like a form, and the main decision you have to make is rather you want it to be controlled (info is stored in stated, and state is reflected in the ui), or uncontrolled (info is taken from the dom once 'Add' is clicked.
- Since you want to empty the input once 'Add' is clicked it makes sense to make this component controlled.
- The next decision is rather you want it to be a functional component, or a class component. In nowadays it doesn't really matter (functional components can now use state with the state hook).
- To store state in you functional component use React's `useState` hook.

```
function Admin({addInfo}){
    const [productName, setProductName] = useState(")

    return (
        <div>            
            <input 
                 type="text" 
                 placeholder="Product Name" 
                 onChange={(e)=>{
                     setProductName(e.target.value)
                 } 
                 value={prodcutName}>
             </input>
             <button 
                 onClick{(e)=>{
                     props.addInfo({productName})
                     setProductName("")  // Will set the input to an empty string
                 }
             >
                  Add
             </button>
     </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I hope my answer helps. A few comments on smaller issues: - required won't have any effect (it is used in forms when jquery is involved, and it hints to a validator that it is required. This is not the case. If you want it to be required implement it on the buttons click handler. 2. If you start AddInfo with a capital it looks like a component. If it's a function (or a method) it will be more clear if it starts with a small letter.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It says 'useState','setproductName' is not defined. Sorry I am new to this and haven't quite picked up a lot yet. And yes, I removed the 'required' since it doesn't do anything

Comment: Done.Thanks a lot

Comment: My pleasure. If you found it helpful you can upvote, or even mark the answer as accepted :-)

Comment: Upvoted :) Can you also help me out with the same thing but with a file input this time? Here's what I am doing https://codepen.io/hardik150/pen/zgmGqz

Comment: Unfortunatly I don't have much experience with uploading files this way. When you find an answer useful you can upvote it using the upward triangle.

Comment: Oh okay thanks again. And yeah I upvoted it but it won't show because of low reputation :P

Comment: If you use an "npm environment" you can use a dependency to upload files. Check out codeSandBox or StackBlitz and npm.