# How to trigger onChange event if value of input is not change in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am taking input from the user as a file using the below code:

```
render() {
  const handleFileChange: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (e) => {
      e.persist();
      Array.from(e.currentTarget.files || []).forEach(file => {
        let modelname = file.name
        consle.log(modelname)
      });
    };
  return (
   <>
    <input accept=".csar,.yaml" type="file" name="filenameanddata" onChange={(e) => { 
     handleFileChange(e)}} /> 
    <label htmlFor="file">
     <Button className = {inputUploadButton} variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}>Upload
     </Button>
    </label>
  </>
 )
}
```

After taking input files display on UI and I am also given the option to delete them.

But after deleting I want to take the same file name from the user. In that input is not working properly.

How to do that any idea?
or
Is there any way to forcefully call onChange event if an event is not changed?

Comment: `handleFileChange()`

Comment: I am trying with handleFileChange() but its behavior is still same. I am not able to take same input again. @KonradLinkowski

Comment: So maybe the problem is not related to onChange. I guess that you want to use controlled input instead of uncontrolled one.

Comment: But if I am taking another input then it works. only when I am taking same input again then it will not work or onChange is not called

Comment: Becuase you didn't ever clear the value of that input

Comment: Ok, How to do that you have any idea? @KonradLinkowski

Comment: Either do [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42192346/how-to-reset-reactjs-file-input) or use controlled input (use state and pass value to the input)