# How not to display Invalidate File name in File Tag in React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, base64

The file tag where I have declared that only PNG/JPEG files are allowed.

[image]

And according to React Dev Tools it is just working fine meant that the file get added successfully.

[image]

But when I tried to add file with other extensions other than PNG/JPEG the files are not get added but in the frontend I can see the name of the file.

[image]

According to React Dev Tools, File is not get added.

[image]

I just wanted, not display the name of the invalidate files like (.pdf, .mp3, etc).

In the Frontend I just wanted to see **No File Chosen** in place of the Invalidate File name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset ReactJS file input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42192346/how-to-reset-reactjs-file-input)

Comment: That's not what he's asking. What he wants to achieve is that, when a file is not actually selected, because it's wrong format, the name should not appear in the "Choose file" field.

Comment: @Sun Yes, you got me right. Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit file format when using <input type="file">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328947/limit-file-format-when-using-input-type-file)

Comment: @matthiasgiger, even you use this, files with other extensions will be get displayed in the frontend

Comment: @SouvikPal take a look at my answer below doing it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Browser built-in options to manage this are somewhat limited, but you can achieve this by doing it manually like this:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <input
      type="file"
      onChange={(event) => {
        if (!event.target.value.endsWith(".png")) {
          event.target.value = null;
        }
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

This will reset the input unless the file is a PNG.