# Error when using v-model on file input

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a file input and I need to clear it after file is uploaded. I tried setting null value to v-model, but it generated the following error

> File inputs are read only. Use a v-on:change listener instead.

My code is

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" v-model="file" multiple v-on:change="uploadFile" ref="fileInput" />
```

How can I clear the file input in vue.js after upload so that I can upload the same file multiple times continuously

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I clear an HTML file input with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703228/how-can-i-clear-an-html-file-input-with-javascript)

Comment: Try this document.getElementById("fileupload").value = "";

Comment: Can we use v-model to do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it using the ref attribute,

```
this.$refs.fileInput.value = null;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are  using `v-on:change="uploadFile"` and guessing that your `uploadFile` has a success callback.

You can do the following:

- Wrap your input in a form and add a ref attribute to your form:

  ```
  <form ref="myFileInputForm">
        <input id="fileupload" type="file" v-model="file" multiple v-on:change="uploadFile" ref="fileInput" />
   </form>
  ```
- In your successful callback `uploadFile` do this:

  `this.$refs.myFileInputForm.reset();`

Answer (score 0):

File inputs are read only.
don't bind on element, remove `v-model="file"`

Comment: All you did was restate the error. This doesn't provide a solution for when someone may need the effect of binding to a file input.