# React: How to clear file input and data input fields after submitting form?

Tags: reactjs

After I submit my form, which contains data fields and a file field, only the data fields are cleared, but the uploaded file field is kept. See image: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hyfrr.png)

**OnChange Function**

```
    onChange = (e) => {
        if(e.target.name === 'audio') {
            this.setState({
                [e.target.name]: e.target.files[0], loaded: 0,
            }, () => console.log(this.state.audio))

        } else {

            this.setState({
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value
            }, () => console.log(this.state))
        }
    }
```

**Submit Function**

```
      onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let { title, content, audio} = this.state;
    //const story = { title, content, audio};
    let formDataStory = new FormData();
    formDataStory.append('audio', audio);
    formDataStory.append('title', title);
    formDataStory.append('content', content);
    this.props.addStory(formDataStory);
    this.setState({
      title: "",
      content:"",
      audio: ""
    });
  };
```

**Form**

```
  render() {
    const {title, content, audio} = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="card card-body mt-4 mb-4">
        <h2>Add Story</h2>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Title</label>
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="text"
              name="title"
              onChange={this.onChange}
              value={title}
            />
             </div>
           <div className="form-group">
            <label>Content</label>
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="text"
              name="content"
              onChange={this.onChange}
              value={content}
            />
          </div>

           <div className="form-group">
            <label>Audio</label>
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="file"
              name="audio"
              onChange={this.onChange}
              //value={audio}
            />
          </div>

         <div className="form-group">
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How can I reset the file upload field together with the other data fields after submitting the form?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since the `file` input is [always uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#the-file-input-tag) you'll need to use a [dom `ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) and manually clear the value.

Here's an example functional component that does this:

```
function ExampleFileInput() {
  const ref = React.useRef();
  function handleClick() {
    ref.current.value = ""
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="file" ref={ref}/><br />
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>Clear file</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

To use in a class component, see [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs). You can read about more ways to clear the file input in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24608023/2178159).

Answer (score 2):

[Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#the-file-input-tag)

1. Create ref to file input `this.inputRef = React.createRef();`
2. add ref to input `<input type="file" ref={this.inputRef} />`
3. Inside submit function `this.inputRef.current.value = '';`

Answer (score 1):

If you use Formik you can do this:

I had the same issue and I managed it creating a ref in the parent component (the one that use Formik) and passing it to the `Field` using `innerRef` prop.
Then on the `onReset` I used the ref to clear the real input value.

```
const UserForm = props => {
    const logoRef = useRef();

    const handleReset = (values, formikBag) => {
        logoRef.current.value = null; //THIS RESETS THE FILE FIELD
    }

    const handleSubmit = (values, formikBag) => {
        //...
        axios({method, url, data})
            .then(response => {
                formikBag.resetForm();
            })
    }
    //...
    return (
        <Formik initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={handleSubmit} onReset={handleReset}>
            ...
            <Field
                type="file"
                name="logo"
                onChange={({target}) => setFieldValue(props.name, target.files[0])}
                innerRef={logoRef}
            />
        </Formik>
    )
}
```