# How to clear file input on button click in react class component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want the selected file to be removed when I click the button. Using the below example

```
this.state{ file:null}

 <input type="file" onChange={this.handleFile}/>
 
<button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Continue</>


handleSubmit (){
      this.setState({file: null})
      }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I clear an HTML file input with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703228/how-can-i-clear-an-html-file-input-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

It is basically impossible to change the text in an input/type=file field. The reason for this is that it would open up a huge security hole.

Try using an <input type=reset> button?