# How to clear FileList Jquery (JavaScript)

Tags: jquery, ajax, filelist

I'm uploading files ajax jquery, and i need clear filelist array.
How i can clear FileList array by input id or other options please;

This code:

```
document.getElementById("myInputFileID").value=null;
```

Not working

Comment: That should work, there is something else in your code that is preventing this from happening. Add [mcve] or it's not possible to help you further.

Comment: Sorry, I found a solution in the topic you threw off, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
var $input = $("#control");

$input.replaceWith($input.val('').clone(true));
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47795271/15331960