# How to wrap an input file in a form using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function:-

```
function resetInputFile(elem) {
    elem.wrap('<form>').closest('form').get(0).reset();
    elem.unwrap();
}
```

I call the function like this:-

```
resetInputFile(document.queryElement('#image'));
```

How can I convert the LOCs

```
elem.wrap('<form>').closest('form').get(0).reset();
elem.unwrap();
```

into pure javascript?

I want to implement the logic in ReactJS, but I don't want to use jquery with ReactJS. So I need to do it with pure javascript.

Comment: Do you have to do it this way or you just want to reset the file input ?
You could just reset it with `document.getElementById("myFile").value = "";`

Comment: @OmarAtri `document.getElementById("myFile").value = ""` doesn't clear the previously selected file from the file input. I had tested it before and that's why I chose wrap() and unwrap() method previously in another PHP project where I could use JQuery.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I clear an HTML file input with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703228/how-can-i-clear-an-html-file-input-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

```js
function resetInputFile(elem) {
  const form = document.createElement('form');
  const parent = elem.parentNode;

  parent.insertBefore(form, elem);
  form.appendChild(elem);
  form.reset();
  parent.insertBefore(elem, form);
  parent.removeChild(form);
}

function resetFileInput() {
  resetInputFile(document.querySelector('#image'));
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="image">
<button onclick="resetFileInput()">Reset File Input</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function resetInputFile() {
  const elem = document.getElementById('image'); //--Get the input element

  const form = document.createElement('form'); //--> Create a <form> element
  const parent = elem.parentNode;//-- Get the parent node of elem

  //-->Replace elem with the newly created form, moving elem inside the form
  parent.replaceChild(form, elem);
  form.appendChild(elem);

  //--Reset the form
  if (form && form.parentNode) {
    form.reset();
    // Restore elem to its original position outside the form
    form.parentNode.replaceChild(elem, form);
  }

  // Unwrap the element
  if (elem.parentNode) {
    const grandParent = elem.parentNode.parentNode; //--> Get the grandparent node
    grandParent.replaceChild(elem, elem.parentNode); //--->Replace form with elem
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="image" />
 <button onclick="resetInputFile()">Reset Input File</button>
```