# How to change the button text of <input type="file" />?

Tags: html, input

```
<input type="file" value="Browse" name="avatar" id="id_avatar" />
```

I tried to modify the `value`, but it's not working. How to customize the button text?

Comment: Are you talking about the filename or the button text?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to rename HTML "browse" button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163667/how-to-rename-html-browse-button)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/210643

Comment: There are pseudo elements like [`::file-selector-button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::file-selector-button) now. Maybe these can be used somehow.

Answer (score 149):

Use [Bootstrap FileStyle](http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/), which is used to style the file fields of forms. It is a plugin for a jQuery-based component library called Twitter Bootstrap

Sample usage:

Include:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js"> </script>
```

Via JavaScript:

```
$(":file").filestyle();
```

Via data attributes:

```
<input type="file" class="filestyle" data-classButton="btn btn-primary" data-input="false" data-classIcon="icon-plus" data-buttonText="Your label here.">
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me. It still shows the brorser's default buttons. Also, the demo at  https://github.com/markusslima/bootstrap-filestyle.git doesn't work either - all examples show the default buttons. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Tony Uhh.... what makes you think Bootstrap isn't using the "wacky <img/> hack" underneath as well?  :-)

Comment: @Ya can you tell what browser and it version? Tested now on Chrome Version 43.0.2357.130 (64-bit) on Linux and all examples works perfectly.

Comment: @Andz What underlying code does has no interest to me, as the presentation layer is semantically unobtrusive here.

Comment: Throwing a javascript library (with a plugin!) on such a small problem is an inelegant overkill.

Comment: BFS disables the ability to drag/drop files onto the browse button.

Comment: Downvoted. It is not even an answer, only a workaround that needs an extra library. The answer should intend to change the rendering behaviour for browsers.

Comment: Change data-buttonText to data-text :) Working now.

Answer (score 146):

Hide the file input. Create a new input to capture a click event and forward it to the hidden input:

```
<input type="button" id="loadFileXml" value="loadXml" onclick="document.getElementById('file').click();" />
<input type="file" style="display:none;" id="file" name="file"/>
```

Comment: throwing in an HTA file with ie7 mode I had to remove the `;` at the end.

Comment: great, don't want to include bootstrap just to change two words of text, but how would you do it if the file-input was created dynamically?

Comment: @asparism use JavaScript to manipulate the DOM, hide it by setting it's style and use before() and add the new input element?

Comment: Since I wasn't able to access the `uploadImgFile.change` handler when dynamically adding an event listener to the new button, I actually ended up using a label element with the for attribute set to the file input's id.

Comment: @MushyPeas it is the easiest way. tried to play with css but this solution is much faster and easier. thanks

Comment: This is the easiest way to tackle this issue. Just to add, we also need to have a label field to display the path of the selected file to the user. Update the label with the value of the input field on onChange event. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It works perfectly for me, it's a cool hack tho :)
Just one thing : doing it, when I choose a file and validate, the path to the file doesn't display after choosing -it did with the original input, a solution ? I'm working on it

Comment: This was the easiest way for me, too! It also allowed me to STYLE the 'mock' file-button as one of a set of other form-button options - without having to worry about displaying the odd-looking "Browse" file-button.

Comment: Instead of using js to click the input, you can use a label and set its "for" attribute to the id of the input.

Comment: This works as well, but we do not get the look of a button and that's what a button does, you click them, something happens. But with a label nobody expects any action by clicking a label, if they even try it.

Comment: Super.. even used the same style and exact words from real hidden button. The best solution so far.

Answer (score 123):

You can put an image instead, and do it like this:

HTML:

```
<img src="/images/uploadButton.png" id="upfile1" style="cursor:pointer" />
<input type="file" id="file1"  name="file1" style="display:none" />
```

JQuery:

```
$("#upfile1").click(function () {
    $("#file1").trigger('click');
});
```

**CAVEAT**:
In IE9 and IE10 if you trigger the onClick in a file input via javascript, the form will be flagged as 'dangerous' and cannot be submitted with javascript, not sure if it can be submitted traditionally.

Comment: This is a clever solution. Couldn't you also do this with a <button> element?

Comment: @Code Commander -Thanks, and yes, you can do it with every element you want, but the most common is the <image> element. Just get rid of the button+text field of the "file input"...

Comment: Just a heads up to anyone using the above, some mobile browsers disable triggering file input clicks programmatically. Specifically, android 4 for the Galaxy S III

Comment: I am using `<input type="file" ` inside asp.net gridview row, whose rows can be added dynamically.. so it will be a real pain in the head to call the relevant input click trigger (of the same row) while clicking on an image! :/

Comment: your solution doesnt work. You prolly didn't set border, margin, padding and background-color or or else it would be obvious

Comment: Also in IE7  the form won't be submitted in this way.

Answer (score 50):

The "upload file..." text is pre-defined by the browser and can't be changed.
The only way to get around this is to use a Flash- or Java-based upload component like [swfupload](http://www.swfupload.org).

Comment: Can you prove it that it can't be changed?

Comment: Or by browsing the browsers' source codes, at least for the Open Source ones.

Comment: This could by the answer (to another question, something like "Why is the content of value, 'VALUE="C:\someFile.txt"' for an input field of type file, 'TYPE="FILE"', ignored by the browser?"): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342039

Comment: Loving the oldschoolness of this answer :D

Answer (score 35):

Works **Perfectly on All Browsers** Hope it will work for you too.

**HTML:**
`<input type="file" class="custom-file-input">`

**CSS:**

```
 .custom-file-input::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.custom-file-input::before {
  content: 'Select some files';
  display: inline-block;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #e3e3e3);
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  outline: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 10pt;
}
.custom-file-input:hover::before {
  border-color: black;
}
.custom-file-input:active::before {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e3e3e3, #f9f9f9);
}
```

Change `content: 'Select some files';` with the text you want within `''`

**IF NOT WORKING WITH firefox then use this instead of input:**

```
<label class="custom-file-input" for="Upload" >
</label>

<input id="Upload" type="file" multiple="multiple" name="_photos" accept="image/*" style="visibility: hidden">
```

Comment: Works on Safari, though

Comment: Its working perfectly at my end on my FF 41.0.2.You are running in to cross browser compatibility issue please refer to CSS BOX MODEL to minify the issue.

Comment: [This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e0t1swh8/) is not working for me on Firefox 42.0.  On safari, it works.  Can you confirm it works on FF 41.0.2?

Comment: Not working for me on FF 41.0.2 (I downloaded a copy).  Not working for FF42 on windows either.

Comment: Or IE11 (not as much of a problem - I'm not trying to support IE anyway)

Comment: The problem is probably that FF is built on Gecko, not webkit. (my best guess)

Comment: <label id="addButton" for="Upload" style="background-color: #000; color:#fff; padding:4px; border-radius:4px; font-family:monospace;" >Choose Some File
</label>

<input id="Upload" type="file" multiple="multiple" name="_photos" accept="image/*" style="visibility: hidden">

Comment: Any way this can be a <button> instead of a label?

Comment: No it can't be as we are using it with input tags so input goes with legend.

Comment: OK, Thanks!  Check out [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/61zLtzx6/2/).  If you edit your answer with that, I think it's worthy of an upvote :)

Comment: This answers the question exactly , without involving a library. I did have to fiddle with the length in both classes, but other than that, it works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 35):

Simply

```
<label class="btn btn-primary">
  <i class="fa fa-image"></i> Your text here<input type="file" style="display: none;"  name="image">
</label>
```

[Edit with snippet]

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<label class="btn btn-primary">
<i class="fa fa-image"></i> Your text here<input type="file" style="display: none;" name="image">
</label>
```

Comment: I like your solution answer but, how do I change the label text after select a picture?

Answer (score 18):

I think this is what you want:

```
<button style="display:block;width:120px; height:30px;" onclick="document.getElementById('getFile').click()">Your text here</button>


<input type='file' id="getFile" style="display:none">
```

Comment: This did the job.. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

[This](https://github.com/datchung/jquery.inputFileText) is a JQuery plugin to change the button text of an input file element.

Example HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="choose-file" />
```

Example JS:

```
$('#choose-file').inputFileText({
    text: 'Select File'
});
```

Result:

[image: plugin result]

Comment: Not a great solution for 'multiple' files. Does not show more than one file.

Answer (score 10):

```
<input id="uploadFile" placeholder="Choose File" disabled="disabled" />
<div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
    <span>Your name</span>
    <input id="uploadBtn" type="file" class="upload" />
</div>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("uploadBtn").onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value;
 };
```

more http://geniuscarrier.com/how-to-style-a-html-file-upload-button-in-pure-css/

Answer (score 6):

### Use `<label>` for the caption

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='/uploads.php' method=post>
<label for=b1>
    <u>Your</u> caption here
<input style='width:0px' type=file name=upfile id=b1
 onchange='optionalExtraProcessing(b1.files[0])'
 accept='image/png'>
</label>
</form>
```

This works **without any javascript**. You can decorate the label to any degree of complexity, to your heart's content. When you click on the label, the click automatically gets redirected to the file input. The file input itself can be made invisible by any method. If you want the label to appear like a button, there are many solutions, e.g.:

```
label u {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance: button;
    appearance: button;

    text-decoration: none;
    color: initial;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I know, nobody asked for it but if anybody is using bootstrap, it can be changed through **Label** and **CSS Pseudo-selector**.

For changing button text:

```
.custom-file-label::after {
  content: "What's up?";
}
```

For changing field text:

```
<label class="custom-file-label" for="upload">Drop it like it's hot</label>
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/actuallyakash/hwmyg2L5/9/).

Comment: This, with [this w3schools trick](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_forms_custom.asp#:~:text=To%20create%20a%20custom%20file,%2Dfile%2Dinput%20to%20it.)  worked very well for me. And since I'm using Bootstrap already, there was no need to install any other plugin.

Answer (score 6):

In Addition to [MushyPeas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36248168/4367848), you can add a **label to show the filename** like so (no jQuery needed):
Credits also to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9234894/4367848).

```html
<input type="button" id="click-input" value="Write anything" onclick="document.getElementById('file').click();" />
<label for="click-input" id="file-name">Bla bla</label>
<input type="file" style="display:none;" id="file">
<script>
    inputElement = document.getElementById('file')
    labelElement = document.getElementById('file-name')
    inputElement.onchange = function(event) {
        var path = inputElement.value;
        if (path) {
            labelElement.innerHTML = path.split(/(\\|\/)/g).pop()
        } else {
            labelElement.innerHTML = 'Bla bla'
        } 
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Only CSS & bootstrap class

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-md-4 input-group">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" />
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <label for="files" class="btn btn-default">browse</label>
    <input id="files" type="file" class="btn btn-default" style="visibility:hidden;" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

In Bootstrap +4.5 you can simply add this to your code:

```css
.custom-file-input~.custom-file-label::after {
  content: "Your custom text ...";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" class="custom-file-input">
  <label class="custom-file-label">Your custom placeholder ...</label>
</div>
```

Comment: See this answer to display the file name of the selected file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69398675/7335274 
You will need to modify the IDs of the label and input in the JavaScript code.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**: I see now by the comments that you are asking about the button text, and not the file path. My bad. I'll leave my original answer below in case someone else who stumbles upon this question interprets it the way I originally did.

**2nd EDIT**: I had deleted this answer because I decided that I misunderstood the question and my answer was not relevant. However, comments in another answer indicated that people still wanted to see this answer so I'm undeleting it.

**MY ORIGINAL ANSWER** (I thought the OP was asking about the path, not the button text):

*This is not a supported feature for security reasons*. The Opera web browser used to support this but it was removed. Think about what would be possible if this were supported; You could make a page with a file upload input, pre-populate it with a path to some sensitive file and then auto-submit the form using javascript triggered by the `onload` event. This would happen too fast for the user to do anything about it.

Answer (score 3):

## What about icons without using real images and "interactivity"?

Check the following example that doesn't use any image, not even javascript, and also it is interactive in the sense that changes its look on mouse events as on mouse-over and on mouse left or right click.

```css
input
{
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

input::file-selector-button
{
  display: none;
}

input::before
{
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 3px 8px 3px 8px;
  color: red;
  content: attr(value)' Some more text';
  margin: 25px;
  padding: 5px;
}

input:hover:before
{
  border: 1px groove blue;
  background: lime;
}

input:active:before
{
  border: 1px groove blue;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" value=" Open..." />
```

## How it works:

Basically, it hides the main button of the standard file input element and shows its pseudo element, indicated by the **:before** part. Than it styles how it looks like and also some mouse events, so it is kind of "interactive".

Also using the :file-selector-button pseudo-element, allows to style the button it self or even to not display it at all as I have done int the above example with the code **display: none;**. This allows to use the **:before** element as replacement of the button.

The advantage of doing it with css is that by not using any javascript it will work even if the user's browser has javascript disabled.

### About the folder icon:

Actually it is a char it self in UNICODE:  that is U+1F4C2 code-point. To see it correctly the user of the page must have a font that supports it. I did not install any new font into my system (Win7) and I see it correctly: so I suppose it is correctly seen by everyone else.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to "change" the text of an input with file type, with pure HTML and javascript:

```
<input id='browse' type='file' style='width:0px'>
<button id='browser' onclick='browse.click()'>
    *The text you want*
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Before that `<input type="file">`, add an image and `<input style="position:absolute">` it will occupy the space of `<input type="file">`
2. Use the following CSS to the file element

   ```
   position:relative;  
   opacity:0;  
   z-index:99;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add some css trick. you **don't need javascript** or more input files and i keep **existing value attribute**. you need to add **only css**. you can try this solution.

```css
.btn-file-upload{
     width: 187px;
     position:relative;
 }

.btn-file-upload:after{
    content:  attr(value);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;    
    width: 48%;
    background: #795548;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 2;
 }
```

```html
<input type="file" class="btn-file-upload" value="Uploadfile" />
```

Answer (score 1):

for me it does not work the custom text with *bootstrap-filestyle*. It help with button decoration but text its weird to be changed, before get into wrestling with css i try the following :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('.buttonText').html('Seleccione ficheros');
});
```

bootstrap-filestyle render the component as span with a class named butonText, so when document load just change the text. easy right and it must work on all browsers.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

if you using rails and have problem apply it, I would like to add some tips from original answer posted by @Fernando Kosh

- Download file [zip](http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/) and copy file bootstrap-filestyle.min.js ke folder app/assets/javascripts/
- open your application.js and add this line below

  //= require bootstrap-filestyle.min
- open your coffee and add this line

  $(":file").filestyle({buttonName: "btn-primary",buttonBefore: true,buttonText: " Your text here",icon: false});

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this for my project:

```css
.btn-outlined.btn-primary {
  color: #000;
}
.btn-outlined.btn-primary:active, .btn-outlined.btn-positive:active, .btn-outlined.btn-negative:active {
  color:#000;
}
.btn-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<label for="fileUpload" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-outlined">Your text</label>
<input type="file" id="fileUpload"style="display: none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending Ken Karlo's solution to answer Ragnar's question .

For react I am changing the text via `useState` like this:

```
import { FC, useState } from 'react'
import classNames from 'classnames' // classNames to organize the classes.
import { ComponentPropsWithRef } from 'react'

type Props = ComponentPropsWithRef<'input'>

const UIPanel: FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState<any[]>([])

  const handleFileChange = (event: any) => {
    let cfiles:any[] = event.target.files
    setFiles(files => cfiles)
  }

  let displayText = "Whatever text you want"
  return (
    <>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <span>
        {displayText}  <span style="color:darkgrey" >{files && files.length > 0 ? (files?.length) + " files":"No file chosen"}</span>
        </span>
        <input onChange={(e) => handleFileChange(e)}
                type="file"
                buttonSize="small"
                displayText="Choose Locales Folder"
                files={files}
                webkitdirectory=""
                directory=""
                multiple
                className={classNames('hidden')}
        />
      </label>
    </>
  )
}
```

I am changging the only `files.length` part to mimic the original one,  similarly you can change `displayText` variable to change the instruction text on the button as well.

PS: My usecase is uploading a folder which is why you see `webkitdirectory`,`directory`,`multiple`, if yours is single file you can change accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

This is an alternative solution that may be of help to you. This hides the text that appears out of the button, mixing it with the background-color of the div. Then you can give the div a title you like.

```
<div style="padding:10px;font-weight:bolder; background-color:#446655;color: white;margin-top:10px;width:112px;overflow: hidden;">
     UPLOAD IMAGE <input style="width:100px;color:#446655;display: inline;" type="file"  />
</div>
```

Comment: In Chrome 39 I see both the UPLOAD IMAGE text and the <input> button.  Perhaps chrome's handling of file inputs has changed since you posted this?

Comment: @yan-bellavance what are you doing? If you think an answer is incorrect or not helpful, downvote, but in no way deface it!