# How to change “Choose file” into “Browse”?

Tags: html, file, input, types

I want to change the default value of `<input type="file" />` from “Choose file” to “Browse”. How to do that?

Comment: Good question, I am stunned this has to be asked, and that none of the solutions are simple

Comment: Webkit browsers use the choose file terms.  The solutions below are simple for this problem.  Using JS to simulate a button click is a very common solution web developers use, allowing them to lay out a page as the designer intended and be visually similar across browsers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the button text of <input type="file" />?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944267/how-to-change-the-button-text-of-input-type-file)

Answer (score 25):

Hide it and use a other control to trigger it.

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('fileID').click(); return false;" />Browse</a>
<input type="file" id="fileID" style="visibility: hidden;" />
```

Comment: I used this solution but styled it as a button using bootstrap and also added display:none so as to not add extra space for the input control.


`<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('fileID').click(); return false;">Browse</a>
<input id="fileID" type="file" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;" />`

Answer (score 6):

I created a jsFiddle to show how, you can find it here: [`Custom browse button`](http://jsfiddle.net/X3S4a/)

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution; hiding file-type input field (button) and placing another regular button-type input field (button) which allows one to change its content - triggering first file button (lower one) is done with JavaScript clicking on second regular button (upper one).

→ [Howto Style the Button of a input type="file" Control](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/154/howto-style-the-button-of-a-input-typefile-control)

Comment: It seems as if in all the comments here, there is no simple easy way to change the default value.