# Change "Choose File" button and keep showing the file name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

It is an old question, but I have not found a solution that fulfils my need.

First, I want to change to `Choose File` to another button style (eg, `btn btn-primary`). Second, after choosing a file, I still want its name to be shown on the screen, so that people know what has been chosen.

I have tried two solutions in `Chrome 53.0.2785.116`. They do change the text of `Choose File`, whereas none of them shows the file name in response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function performClick(elemId) {
      var elem = document.getElementById(elemId);
      if(elem && document.createEvent) {
      var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
      evt.initEvent("click", true, false);
      elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="uploadfile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <!-- http://stackoverflow.com/a/16015086/702977 -->
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('file').click(); return false;">Browse</a> <input id="file" name="file" type="file" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;" />

    <!-- http://stackoverflow.com/a/6463467/702977 -->
    <!-- <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="performClick('file');">Choose File</a><input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="position: fixed; top: -100em" />-->

    <input type="submit" id="u_button" name="u_button" value="Upload the file">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/cacaco/1/edit?html,output)

Does anyone have a solution? I am open to non-purely HTML solution as well (eg, JQuery)...

Comment: For security reasons, JS never exposes the actual file path of a selected file to the browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript, jquery-ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)

Comment: Guys, I made a mistake, I want to show `file name` rather than `file path`...

Comment: You can access the file name by accessing the `value` attribute of the input. Some OS/browsers may supply a dummy path, so you might want to use regex to parse the value to obtain the file name. And again, **this question has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189615/how-to-get-file-name-when-user-select-a-file-via-input-type-file**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function to handle `change` event at `<input type="file">` element, create a `<label>` element with `for` attribute set to `input type="file"` `id`, set `.webkitRelativePath` of `File` object,  , `File` object `.name` or  `.value` property of `input` element, sliced from last `\` character to end of string, set `.innerHTML` of `<label>` element to resulting string

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     function performClick(elemId) {
     var elem = document.getElementById(elemId);
     if(elem && document.createEvent) {
     var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
     evt.initEvent("click", true, false);
     elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
     }
     }
        
        function handleFile(elem) {
          console.log(elem.files[0].name, elem.value);
          document.querySelector("[for='file']")
          .innerHTML = elem.files[0].webkitRelativePath 
                       || elem.files[0].name
                       || elem.value.slice(
                           elem.value.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1
                          );
        }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="uploadfile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    
    <!-- http://stackoverflow.com/a/16015086/702977 -->
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('file').click(); return false;">Browse</a> <input id="file" name="file" type="file" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;" onchange="handleFile(this)" />
    
    <!-- http://stackoverflow.com/a/6463467/702977 -->
    <!-- <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="performClick('file');">Choose File</a><input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="position: fixed; top: -100em" />-->

 <input type="submit" id="u_button" name="u_button" value="Upload the file"><label for="file"></label>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```