# How do you change the default folder of a select file?

Tags: html

How do you change the default folder of a choose file button? I've made a choose file button. When you click it, I want it to open a specific folder. Please help! Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change “Choose file” into “Browse”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281430/how-to-change-choose-file-into-browse)

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible, as it is a security risk to let website code set any value on the machine.

Also, you can never be sure that directory exists. What if I'm on a Mac? My stuff are in ~/Pictures. What if I installed Windows on D:\?

All credit goes to [casraf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/280143/casraf) for this answer.