# How to change the button text of input type="file" element

Tags: javascript, html

Well I am developing a simple page in html, in which I am using `input element type="file"`. By default we get a textbox  and a button to browse a file from the system. Default label of this button is Browse. But I want to change the label of this button with some other name, like 'Open' or 'Select File'. But I don't have any idea how to accomplish this.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: It cannot be done. It's OS behaviour.

Comment: It is not possible in HTML.You can do it using Jquery plugin Uploadify see www.uploadify.com.

Comment: By the way, I think this question is been asked many times here on SO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the button text of <input type="file" />?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944267/how-to-change-the-button-text-of-input-type-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use an image and overlay it on top of the button. then use Javascript to clone the file click onto the image. Does this even make sense? I'm a bit hungover. 
Anyway, here's a ncie jQuery plugin http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/filestyle/demo.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You could if you would use Flash or Java for handling file uploads.

Answer (score 0):

you can not change file control "Browse" text, you can do this if you use jquery file upload...