# html div vertical alignment

Tags: html, css

Can anyone please help me in aligning this divs vertically i want `secondDiv` to come below `firstDiv`. i saw many posts but not able to resolve it can anyone change my code to work it.

```
<div>
    <div style="position:relative;width:800px;margin:0;padding:0">
        <div id="firstDiv" style="text-align:center;position:absolute;margin-top:0">
            <div>
                <span>
                    <input type="submit" title="" value="Select Photos From Your Computer"
                    name="sendBtn">
                </span>
            </div>
            <div style="width:492px;height:20px;position:absolute;top:8px;overflow:hidden;z-index:100">
                <form target="msa_frame" name="picForm" id="picForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" style="opacity:0;font-size:20px;" accept="image/*"
                    name="d" id="d">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="secondDiv" style="text-align:center;margin:3px 0 12px;">
            <span>You can add upto</span>
            <span style="font-weight:bold">3 Photos</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the "position:absolute" from firstDiv's style attribute, and it seems to answer your question.

This also results in things moving around. So you need to describe exactly what you want.

You should avoid using position:absolute and position:fixed unless you are doing something fancy (eg. a menu bar, or a window popup within a window). So remove all "position:..." stuff as well as "top:...".

And why do you have that opacity 0 file input in the middle? If you want it to hide and also remove the empty space, change that to "display: none" (and to unhide: "display: block" (like a div) or "display: inline" (like a span))

Here it is with the opacity changed to display, and all positioning stuff (top:, position:, etc.) removed.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div style="width: 800px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px">   
            <div id="firstDiv" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 0">
                <div>
                    <span>
                        <input type="submit" title="" value="Select Photos From Your Computer" name="sendBtn" />
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div style="width:492px; height:20px; overflow:hidden; z-index:100">
                    <form target="msa_frame" name="picForm" id="picForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type="file" style="display: none; font-size:20px;" accept="image/*" name="d" id="d" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="secondDiv" style="text-align: center; margin: 3px 0 12px;">
                You can add up to
                <span style="font-weight:bold">3 Photos</span>
            </div>   
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

After reading your comments on other's answers, try this: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944267/how-to-change-the-button-text-of-input-type-file

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `position: absolute;` from the `firstDiv` it will work ... [see here for an example](http://jsfiddle.net/vSp4n/)

Comment: Ya that works  but you can see in my first div i am absoluting button and file input so that the user believes that they are clicking the button. I need this functionality is there anyway without removing absolute.

Comment: @saravananshanmugavel I really dont understand what you are trying to do ... perhaps update your question with the problem you face - rather than asking a question about positioning

Comment: Sorry yar got it after removed that position it worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

remove `position:absolute;` for `firstdiv`

Answer (score 0):

changed in div like

```
>  <div id="firstDiv" style="text-align:center;margin-top:0;">
```

and you will get like this output

[image]