# Change default button label of <p:fileUpload mode="simple">

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces, label

I am using `<p:fileUpload mode="simple">`. The button label shows differently in Chrome and Firefox. I would like it to be the same across browsers. I tried changing it by setting the `label` attribute as follows:

```
<p:fileUpload label="Browse" ... mode="simple" />
```

However, it had no effect. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's **not** possible in current PrimeFaces 3.x version. It's only possible when you use `mode="advanced"` instead of `mode="simple"`.

As to your attempt to use the `label` attribute, this attribute is only used as label in validation error messages associated with the input component. With your `label="Browse"` attempt, in case of a `required="true"` validation error, the message would appear like so "Browse is required" instead of "formId:inputId is required".

---

**Update:** since PrimeFaces 5.x, you can add `skinSimple="true"` to give `mode="simple"` the desired skin/look'n'feel as the remainder. Also, the `label` will actually be used as button label. See also the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml).

```
<p:fileUpload label="Browse" ... mode="simple" skinSimple="true" />
```

Answer (score 8):

I'm using PrimeFaces 5.0, and it's possible change the default names in advanced mode: Choose - Upload - Cancel
You can use: label="" uploadLabel="" cancelLabel="" to set your custom names.

The implementation is here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/single.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

Look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18909078. We run with a similar problem on our Web site and we plan looking closer at that Bootstrap filestyle plugin http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/.