# Asp:FileUpload edit "No file selected" message

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, asp.net-webpages

I just need to know if there's a way to **change the message** shown by the `Asp:FileUpload` when no file as been selected.

[image: This message]

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469844/change-default-button-label-of-pfileupload-mode-simple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You replace the text with your own message using CSS pseduo-class `:after`. You can declare a class like this one:

```
.bar:after {
    content:"Please select a file";
    background-color:white;
}
```

And assign it to your FileUpload control. The content message will replace the original one. Of course upon file selection you need to remove the message, you can do this for example via jQuery `.removeClass` (assuming ID of your FileUpload is "foo"):

```
$('#foo').change(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("bar");
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5zhuL/2/

Note that this solution seems to work Webkit-browser's only (Chrome, Opera, Safari) you may need an alternative for others.

Answer (score 5):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZDgRG/

See above link. I use css to hide the default text and use a label to show what I want:

html

```
<div>
      <input type='file' title="Choose a video please" id="aa" onchange="pressed()">
      <label id="fileLabel">Choose file</label>
</div>
```

css

```
input[type=file]{
    width:90px;
    color:transparent;
}
```

javascript

```
window.pressed = function(){
    var a = document.getElementById('aa');
    if(a.value == "")
    {
        fileLabel.innerHTML = "Choose file";
    }
    else
    {
        var theSplit = a.value.split('\\');
        fileLabel.innerHTML = theSplit[theSplit.length-1];
    }
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope, not possible.  This is the standard rendering in Chrome and cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you visit your page source in your browser ASP.NET put an input element with `type='file'` instead of your FileUpload.
You could simply use CSS to cover the text with something when the value attribute is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Only add this CSS to your code. It simply hide the "No file chosen".

```
<style>
 input[type=file]
{
width:90px;
color:transparent;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Lsgbx5ne/1/

```
input[type=file]{
  color:transparent;
}
input[type=file]:after {
  color: #000;
  content:" Cool!";
}
```

Improvements over other solutions:

- Works for short text
- Doesn't change the background color
- Pure css

Answer (score 0):

**This work in all browser**

```js
window.pressed = function(){
    var a = document.getElementById('aa');
    if(!(a.value == ""))
    {
        var theSplit = a.value.split('\\');
        fileLabel.innerHTML = theSplit[theSplit.length-1];
    }
};
```

```css
input[type=file]{
    width:90px;
    color:transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>
<input type='file' title="Choose a video please" id="aa" onchange="pressed()">
<label id="fileLabel">Choose file</label>
</div>
```