# Change Default Label on FileUpload

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I have an ASP.NET program and I want to change by code the default Text on it witch is 
"No file chosen"

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201424/aspfileupload-edit-no-file-selected-message or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035400/how-can-i-remove-the-no-file-chosen-tooltip-from-a-file-input-in-chrome

Comment: Can I edit it using c# or asp code?