# Display text "loading..." after file is selected in input type="file" element

Tags: javascript, forms, upload

I am using a really simple form to allow users to upload files to my server. It works well, but i have noticed that even for very small files, right after selecting the file to upload, it takes a while (2-3 sec) to change the "No file selected" to the actual name of the file selected. (Actually it says it in spanish - guess somebody knows where i am).

The thing is that during this loading time the mouse wheel nor the browser look like they are thinking, so im afraid the user wont be patient enough and will feel its not working.

So i just want to display a text saying, "hey, hold on - its loading" And this is what i have tried with no luck:

A.

```
<input type="file" name="userf" onload="function(e){e.innerHTML='Loading';};">
</input>
```

B.

```
<input type="file" name="userf" onchange="function(e){e.innerHTML='Loading';};">
</input>
```

C.

```
<input type="file" name="userf" onload="function(){this.innerHTML='Loading';};">
</input>
```

D.

```
<input type="file" name="userf" onchange="function(){this.innerHTML='Loading';}">
</input>
```

If this is not possible, could i not just change the default message: "No file selected"?

EDIT
If possible, no JQuery, just javascript

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the default text on an input file element. But you can do some work arounds in order to get something similar you want. It may require jQuery or other framework to do the job.

This post may help: [How to change the button text of <input type="file" />?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944267/how-to-change-the-button-text-of-input-type-file)

Comment: Thanks, that seems a bit overcomplicated for what i want.. i dont mind if the text stays there like it is by default as long as i can show "loading..." elsewhere, only while its loading of course : )