# How to change the "Browse" button text

Tags: html, css, spring, jsp, browser

I need to change the "Browse" button text according to the locale in a **JSP**. (Ex. Russian , Portuguese) for a **Spring** based project.

Following is the current implementation for the browse button

```
<td><input type="file" id="file" name="fileName"/></td>
```

[image]

As I know we can't change the text for input type **file**. It's the default behavior for a browse button int he browser.

I tried the following solution

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="Browse"/>
<input type="file" id="fileName"  style="opacity:0; position:relative; left:-40px;"  onchange="javascript: document.getElementById ('fileName').value = this.value"/>
```

[image]

But above one is giving security issue in the browser.

---

In https://stackoverflow.com/ it's having the ideal solution for this (change text for the browse button using input type **file**):

[image]

```
<input type="file" name="filename" id="filename-input" value="browse" size="18" style="float: right; width: 250px;">
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this problem or the way to implement above solution( https://stackoverflow.com/ file upload).

Comment: what kind of security issue it gives?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the button text of <input type="file" />?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944267/how-to-change-the-button-text-of-input-type-file)

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18909078/468763) to a similar question.

It suggests using [Bootstrap File-system](http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/) css styling.

Answer (score 0):

suggest you to do it this way to keep it simple:

```
<input type="file" style="display:none"/>
<button id="browse">whatever</button>

$('#browse').click(function(){
    $('input[type="file"]').trigger('click');
});
```