# I can't edit my <input type="file"> tag

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot edit this button, I tried using bootstrap javascript. Here's a sample of my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap-filestyle.js"> </script>
        <script>
            $(":file").filestyle({input: false});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="file" class="filestyle" data-input="false">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: just make the input[type=file] clear or hidden and use a <label for=inpFiles><button>Choose File</button></label> combo to trigger clicks on the file input while accepting CSS styles on the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you can't. The text is predefined by the browser.

A workaround might be to use an image or a third party file uploader.
Check out this related answer: [How to change the button text of <input type="file" />?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944267/how-to-change-the-button-text-of-input-type-file)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is replace the text "Choose file" into something else;

If that is the case try the following statement.

Sorry, not enough reputation to comment.

```
<input type='file' style='opacity: 0; width:90px; position: absolute; z-index:2'>
<button class='btn-margin btn grey' style='z-index: 1;width:90px;cursor:pointer;'>Browse</button>";
```