# Change file input button's Text when the user chooses his/her file

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this file input:

```
<input id="some_file_input" type="file"  name="some_file" class="custom-input-thing" data-buttonName="btn-primary" data-icon="true">
```

i hide the text that comes with the button, the one that says "no file selected", just becouse of the "looks":

```
input[type=file] {
color: transparent; 
display: block;
```

}

Is there a way to change the text of the file input when the user selects the file to upload??

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944267/how-to-change-the-button-text-of-input-type-file

Comment: @Popnoodles is not the same question. Mine is asking to check when the user selects the file and THEN chenge the text property

Comment: For which you could fill in the gaps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `inputFileText` plugin for this

https://github.com/datchung/jquery.inputFileText

Load this file after jQuery

```
<script src='jquery-input-file-text.js'></script>
```

Here is your jQuery code.

```
$("input[type=file]").on("change", function() {
    $(this).inputFileText( { text: 'Uploaded' } );
});
```

If a file is updated, the value of `input[type=file]` will be changed. We use the `change` event handler. Then we include the plugin function for changing the text.