# Label doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```css
.hidden_element {
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <label for="file">
    <button type="button" class="button red">Choose File</button>
  </label>
  <div class="hidden_element">
    <input type="file" name="video" id="file" />
  </div>
</form>
```

The problem is when I click choose file nothing happens.

Comment: This button does nothing. What do you want it to do? And why would you put it into label?

Comment: You are hiding the input type for uploading the file.

Comment: Perhaps you should use plain text or span styled as button inside `label` if you want label to work.

Comment: It won't work because the `button` does not `focus`, the `label` does. Replace the `label` with just text and it starts working.

Comment: Maybe this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944267/how-to-change-the-button-text-of-input-type-file

Comment: You have no javascript here; the code you provided does nothing. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @SergiyT. thanks, your solution works

Answer (score 4):

Change your button like  `<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('file').click()" class="button red">Choose File</button>`

```css
.hidden_element {
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <label for="file">
    <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('file').click()" class="button red">Choose File</button>
  </label>
  <div class="hidden_element">
    <input type="file" name="video" id="file" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: that works, thank you! But why the `<label for="file">` didn't work? 

Answer (score 0):

The label element applies to one input only: since it has one as a child (the button is an input element), it applies to it instead of the file-input as you hoped.

Just remove the button, maybe replace it with a span and style it as you wish, and clicking the label will open the file picker. No javascript needed! :)

```css
.hidden_element {
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eee, #ccc);
  padding: 0.1em 0.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <label for="file">
    <span class="button red">Choose File</span>
  </label>
  <div class="hidden_element">
    <input type="file" name="video" id="file" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

I do not see the purpose of putting the button as a label.  Either use a button or a submit to process your input (file upload).  You should not hide your 'input file' tag.  You really need two things for the user: the 'input file' tag to allow the user to choose the file he wants to upload and then a way to perform an action by submitting the form or perhaps an ajax call.  However, since you are just learning this process, I recommend, just performing a simple submit and for you to write the code on the backend that will handle uploading the file.  Here is a sample of my html code:

```html
<form method="post" action="uploadFile.php">
 <input type="file" name="video" id="file" />
 <br /><br />
 <input type="submit" value="upload file">
</form>
```