# A text bar that replaces "Choose file"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have the following code ([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/mezoso/4/edit?html,css,output)) which creates a form:

```
  <form class="form" method="post" action="upload.php">
    <div class="form-group email">
      <!-- <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email</label> -->
      <input name="f_email" id="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email:">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group file">
      <!-- <label class="sr-only" for="file">File</label> -->
      <input name="file" id="file" type="file" class="form-control" placeholder="Click to choose file:">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
  </form>
```

Now I want to apply the style of `Email` to `Choose file`: I don't want to see the `Choose file` button, I want to see a text bar filled with `Click to choose file:` (as the text bar filled with `Email:`).

I tried

```
<input name="file" id="file" type="file" class="form-control" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;" placeholder="Click to choose file:">
```

or

```
<input name="file" id="file" type="file" class="form-control" style="position: relative; top: -1000px;" placeholder="Click to choose file:">
```

But they both removed the `file` line.

I will add an onclick event (to launch a file browser) and a change event (to display the chosen file name in the bar), but before that, does anyone know how to show the bar as I described above?

Additionally, does anyone know how to display the email bar and the file bar in the same line?

**Update 1:** It is good to know [Bootstrap FileStyle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18909078/702977). But it seems that onclick event is disabled in the field. Here is an example: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/mezoso/7/edit?html,css,output).

Comment: Is this different from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944267/how-to-change-the-button-text-of-input-type-file)?

Comment: It is an alternative, but I still don't want to see the button, and the onclick event seems to be disabled. Please see my update...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [**label**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) for the input. That way, when the label is clicked, it will focus the input. See demo below:

```css
.fakeInput {
  border: 1px solid #9199a1; 
  color: #9199a1; 
  padding: 1px; 
  margin: 2px; 
  font-size: 13.3333px;
  font-family: "Arial";
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: start;
  width: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group email">
      <!-- <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email</label> -->
      <input name="f_email" id="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email:">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group file">
      <input name="file" id="file" type="file" class="form-control" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;">
      <label for="file" class="fakeInput">Click to choose file:</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: do you want it to look like an Email (text) input?

Comment: I don't want to see the `Choose file` button, I want to see a text bar filled with `Click to choose file:` (as the text bar filled with `Email:`)

Comment: okay how about now, where it _simulates_ a text input using styles (which can be moved to CSS)?