# Bootstrap fileupload button stacked beneath default html form button

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap

As shown in the picture below I have bootstrap beneath the standard html form file upload button. How can I remove the standard button and the text. So that it's only the bootstrap button and my own text?

[image]

The text is in danish, but it's the "no file has been chosen"

I use ModelForm to display the form field.

html:

```
<label class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
    {{ field }}
</label>
```

ModelForm:

```
widgets = {
    'image': forms.FileInput(attrs={'class' : 'add-image-upload-hidden'}),
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Posible duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944267/how-to-change-the-button-text-of-input-type-file)

[Use  Bootstrap FileStyle:](http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js"> </script>
```

Changes the button text. Type: String, Default: "Choose file"

Via JavaScript:

```
$(":file").filestyle({buttonText: "Find file"});
```

Via data attributes:

```
<input type="file" class="filestyle" data-buttonText="Find file">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use another button element to wrap your btn-file and add your button text inside it.

**I think this is what you want to achieve**

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       
       </head>
       <body>
       
  <label class="btn btn-primary ">
  <button class="btn btn-file">my own text</button>
    your label
</label>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!