# How to I change image button into image icon in control flow?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms, django-templates

As you can see in the image there is an image input field , i want to change that in image icon, How can i change that in a image icon instead of **browse..** `button` ,
[image]

Inside `form.py` I defined the fields classes :

```
class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ('tag',"title","image_data","body",)

        widgets ={
            'image_data': forms.FileInput(attrs={'class':'control-flow blogimage'})
        }
```

custom.css

```
.blogimage{
    style:fa fa-image;
}
```

html

```
<h1>Create a new blog</h1>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    
    <input type="submit" value='Publish' class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
</form>
```

generated html of imagefield :

```
<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="id_image_data">Image data</label><input type="file" name="image_data" class="blogimage" accept="image/*" title="" required="" id="id_image_data"></div>
```

If more information or code is require than tell me in comments session I will update my question with that information.

Comment: Did you tried to hide the default button and use a clickable icon ... like here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944267/how-to-change-the-button-text-of-input-type-file

Comment: If you post your generated HTML, jQuery developers can solve this problem.

Comment: @quantumPuter sure I am just posting that.

Comment: @quantumPuter I have just posted that now you can see.

Comment: Actually, maybe it is better just to use CSS, like this.  http://jsfiddle.net/t4ry1kd8/